# php how to read xml data file which contain category and sub category

Tags: php, xml

i am trying  read xml file from php and convert data into array here is my xml file code

```
<template>
    <category name="Good">
        <image name="abc" />
        <image name="xyz" />
    </category>
<category name="Baad">
        <image name="123" />
        <image name="asd" />
    </category>
</template>
```

here is my code

```
$source = 'test.xml';

 // load as string
 $xmlstr = file_get_contents($source);
 $xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
 foreach($xmlcont as $url) 
 {

 }
```

can you please tell me how i print all data from xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

 $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

  foreach($xml as $data){

    echo "Category Name : ".$data["name"]."<br>";
    echo "<pre>";
    $count=0;
    foreach($data->image as $key=>$image){
        $count++;
        echo "Image Name $count : ".$image["name"]."<br>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Try this code , its output should be like http://prntscr.com/6aekr7

Answer (score 0):

here is ur code

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("text.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->category[0]->img[name] . "<br>";
echo $xml->category[1]->img[name] . "<br>";
?>
```